# React.DOM: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Being a newbie to the React community...I'm blocked (for hours now) and unable to trace a solution to fix the error posted above:

Am I missing the right parameters to how the data object is fetched in through the app?

This is my ajax data response
[image]

The bug is living on `props.personList.map` inside of **const ListContainer**

For **context** here's the code on the entire file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function getPersonList() {
    const api = 'apistring';
    return axios.get(api).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

let getLastName = (fullName) => {
    return fullName.match(/\w+/g)[1];
};

const getFirstName = (fullName) => {
    return fullName.match(/\w+/g)[0];
};

//Remove any people that do not have the name we are searching for
let filterByName = (searchForName, personList) => {
    return personList.filter((person) => {
        return person.name === searchForName;
    });
};

//VIEW (React)
const Search = ({ onChange }) => React.DOM.input({
    type: 'input',
    onChange
});

const Thumbnail = ({src}) => React.DOM.img({
    className: 'image',
    src
});

//CODE BREAKS HERE
const ListRow = (props) => React.DOM.tr({ key: props.person.name }, [
    React.DOM.td({ key: 'headshot' }, React.createElement(Thumbnail, { src: props.person.url })),
    React.DOM.td({ key: 'firstName' }, null, getFirstName(props.person.name)),
    React.DOM.td({ key: 'lastName' }, null, getLastName(props.person.name)),
]);

const ListContainer = (props) => React.DOM.table({ className: 'list-container' }, [
    React.DOM.thead({ key: 'firstName' }, React.DOM.tr({}, [
        React.DOM.th({ key: 'lastName' }, null, 'headshot'),
        React.DOM.th({ key: 'id' }, null, 'First Name'),
        React.DOM.th({ key: 'last-h' }, null, 'Last Name')
    ])),
    React.DOM.tbody({ key: 'tbody' }, props.personList.map((person, i) =>
        React.createElement(ListRow, { key: `person-${i}`, person })))
]);

const App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            personList: [],
            visiblePersonList: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        getPersonList().then((data) =>
            this.setState({
                data,
                visiblePersonList: data
            }));

    },
    _shuffleList() {
        this.setState({
            visiblePersonList: shuffleList(this.state.personList)
        });
    },
    _sortByFirst() {
        this.setState({
            visiblePersonList: sortByFirstName(this.state.personList)
        });
    },
    _sortByLast() {
        this.setState({
            visiblePersonList: sortByLastName(this.state.personList)
        });
    },
    _onSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            visiblePersonList: filterByName(e.target.value, this.state.personList)
        });
    },
    render() {
        const { visiblePersonList } = this.state;
        return React.DOM.div({ className: 'app-container' }, [
            React.createElement(Search, { key: 'search', onChange: this._onSearch }),
            React.DOM.button({ key: 'shuffle', onClick: this._shuffleList }, null, 'Shuffle'),
            React.DOM.button({ key: 'sort-first', onClick: this._sortByFirst }, null, 'Sort (First Name)'),
            React.DOM.button({ key: 'sort-last', onClick: this._sortByLast }, null, 'Sort (Last Name)'),
            React.createElement(ListContainer, { key: 'list', personList: visiblePersonList })
        ]);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Why mix JSX and `React.DOM` members?

Comment: @DannyDelott Delott Because this code was written on a index.html file to run without any compiling, and I'm now trying to refactor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback with the `console.log` accesses the value and then discards it.

```
function getPersonList() {
    const api = 'apistring';
    return axios.get(api).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

should be

```
function getPersonList() {
    const api = 'apistring';
    return axios.get(api).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.data.items;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

When you use `.then` you are inserting a link into your promise chain. The value returned by `.then` becomes the value passed to the next handler. Because you are not returning any value, your

```
getPersonList().then((data) => {
    // ...
});
```

callback will get `data` as `undefined`.

Another thing to note, though don't cause this specific error, is that your screenshot shows objects with `.firstName` and `.lastName` but all of the code in this file uses `.name` which does not exist.

Comment: loganfsmyth no words to thank you enough sir. Based on the key values of data.items object. How should I replace the .name to be in accordance with the fetched response?

Comment: Probably you'd want to change all the places you use `.name` to manually concatenate the value. You could also concatenate them when you fetch the data, but keeping them separate will make your sorting logic much easier.

Comment: So if I want only the  first name: I would write res.data.items.firstName?